# how to generate 1 million random integers and write them to a file?

Tags: python, file-io, random

I was trying to do some tests on my external sorting algorithms, and I thought I should generate a huge amount of random numbers and put them into a file.

Here is how I do it:

```
import tempfile, random

nf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
i = 0
while i < 1000:
    j = 0
    buf = ''
    while j < 1000:
        buf += str(random.randint(0, 1000))
        j += 1
    nf.write(buf)
    i += 1
```

I thought, I should speed up the generating process by *reducing the File IO operations*, so I use `buf` to store as many numbers as possible, then write buf to the file.

**Question:**

I still got a sense that, the generating and writing process was slow.

Am I getting something wrong?

**EDIT:**

In C++, we can simply write an `int` or a `float` into file by `<<` without `converting them` into string.

So can we do the same in Python? I mean write an integer into file without converting it into str.

Comment: "So can we do the same in Python?".  Yes.  I doubt that's your real question, however.  Perhaps you should rephrase this to give us a better hint what you want to know.  Do you want to know how to write bytes to a file?  Do you want to know how to use `struct` to pack integer values into a sequence of bytes?  I'm guessing that you want to know more than "can we do the same?"  But, it's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @S.Lott, yes sir, indeed I want to know more about `writing bytes to a file` and `how to use struct`.

Comment: Please **update** the question to clarify your question.  It's not easy to gather your meaning from a sequence of comments.  Also.  It isn't helpful to keep adding 'EDIT'.  Just change the question to be correct and complete.  Change the question to say what you **really** need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operating systems are already optimized for such I/O operations.  So, you can directly write the numbers to file and get a very good speed:

```
import tempfile, random

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as nf:
    for _ in xrange(1000000):  # xrange() is more efficient than range(), in Python 2
        nf.write(str(random.randint(0, 1000)))
```

In practice, the numbers will only be written to the disk when the size-optimized file buffer is full.  The code in the question and the code above take the same time, on my machine.  So, I would advise to use my simpler code and to rely on the operating system's built-in optimizations.

If the result fits in memory (which is the case for 1 million numbers), then you can indeed save some I/O operations by creating the final string and then writing it in one go:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as nf:
    nf.write(''.join(str(random.randint(0, 1000)) for _ in xrange(1000000)))
```

This second approach is 30% faster, on my computer (2.6 s instead of 3.8 s), probably thanks to the single write call (instead of a million `write()` calls–and probably many fewer actual disk writes).

The "many big writes" approach of your question falls in the middle (3.1 s).  It can be improved, though: it is clearer and more Pythonic to write it like this:

```
import tempfile, random

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as nf:
    for _ in xrange(1000):
        nf.write(''.join(str(random.randint(0, 1000)) for _ in xrange(1000)))
```

This solution is equivalent to, but faster than the code in the original question (2.6 s on my machine, instead of 3.8 s).

In summary, the first, simple approach above might be fast enough for you.  If it is not and if the whole file can fit in memory, the second approach is both very fast and simple.  Otherwise, your initial idea (fewer writes, bigger blocks) is good, as it is about as fast as the "single write" approach, and still quite simple, when written as above.

Comment: @Alcott: Thanks.  You can directly print objects to a file with `print >> nf, 123` (Python 2) or `print(123, file=nf)` (Python 3).  However, in your case, you do not want `print` to add a space or a newline; this can only be done with `print` in Python 3, as far as I know: `print(123, file=nf, end='')` (by default, `end='\n'`).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use string concatenation in a loop. Use `str.join` instead.

> CPython implementation detail: If s and t are both strings, some Python implementations such as CPython can usually perform an in-place optimization for assignments of the form s = s + t or s += t. When applicable, this optimization makes quadratic run-time much less likely. This optimization is both version and implementation dependent. For performance sensitive code, it is preferable to use the str.join() method which assures consistent linear concatenation performance across versions and implementations.

Your code would look like this:

```
buf = ''.join(str(random.randint(0, 1000)) for j in range(1000))
```

And note that since you have not specified a separator it will look like this:

```
3847018274193258124003837134....
```

Change `''` to `','` if you want the numbers to be (for example) comma separated.

I also don't think you need to buffer yourself as writing to a file should already be buffered.

Comment: Aside from that, a string of 1.000.000 ints isn't going to be that large, looking at today's machines. `nf.write(' '.join(str(random.randint(0,1000)) for j in range(1000000)))` should be fine.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, if it's not 1 million but 1 billion or more, then should it be better if I buffer the numbers instead of write them one-by-one into the file?

Comment: Well, with over 1 billion you'll run into a 2GB limit on 32-bit Python installations (and, unless you have 6 GB RAM or more, probably into memory problems on 64-bit machines, too), so yeah, then it does make sense.

Comment: "will it fit into memory" is the first thing to ask on this kind of problems indeed :)

Comment: @Mark Byers, `writing to a file should already be buffered`? I don't quite understand, do you mean that, every time I use `fp.write(buf)`, the writing doesn't actually happen but `just buffered by the OS`?

Comment: @Alcott: Not immediately, no. If you want to actually perform the write you can call flush, but you aren't doing that (and in this case just closing the file at the end should be sufficient). See EOL's answer for some more specific performance details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671538/how-to-generate-1-million-random-integers-and-write-them-to-a-file/7671701#7671701

Comment: @MarkByers, There is one thing I am not comfortable with, that is if what I have to concatenate 2 string, what should I do? I mean if I have `2 strings: s1 = 'abc'; s2 = '123'`, and I want to put them together like `s1 = 'abc123'`, should I use `s1 += s2` or `s1 = ''.join([s1, s2])`?

Comment: @alcott: If it's just two strings it's fine. A problem can occur if you are concatenating n strings, where n is potentially large.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to generate some random numbers and you are under linux, try shell command

```
for i in {1..1000000}; do echo $[($RANDOM % 1000)]; done > test.in
```

ok, i test this code below, it takes about 5 seconds to finish

```
import tempfile, random

nf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
for i in xrange(0, 1000000):
    nf.write(str(random.randint(0, 1000)))
```

Comment: well, actually I want to know how to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for Python but += is usually an expensive operation as it copies the string to new memory.

Using some string builder or array that you join is probably much faster.

Comment: `string builder or array`? How? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Use Mark Byers response above, he has supplied good examples, I only know the basic principle but don't code python ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
import random
import struct

with open('binary.dat','wb') as output:
     for i in xrange(1000000):
         u = random.randint(0,999999) # number
         b = struct.pack('i', u) # bytes
         output.write(b)
```

This will create 4 million bytes of data.  1 million 4-byte values.

You can read up on `struct` and the various packing options here: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html.

Answer (score -2):

Doing a million of anything is going to be relatively slow.  Also, depending on how random you want the numbers, you may want to invest in a more robust random integer generator.  This is a personal favorite:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister

Comment: He is using the Mersenne Twister - that's what python's built-in random module uses.